# calling GET request after POST request in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous, post, get

I want to call make a GET request after a POST request using Angular.

Here is the code I have so far, is it the good solution?

```
   update(){
     this.http.post<any>("/ssservice", "products=" + body, options)
       .suscribe({
         complete: () => {
           this.http.get<Product[]>("/ssservice")
             .suscribe({
               (data: Product[]) => products.push(...data),
               err => console.log(err)})
         }
       });
    }
```

Any help is greatly aprreciated.

Comment: Yes this is good approach but to be more cleaner code you can call another function having get request code from the success of post request.

Comment: @PardeepJain thank you for your reply. Please provide a detailed answer and be sure I'll mark it as answered and upvote. Thanks in advance

Comment: Added answer, Seems due to network issue answer was saved in draft and someone else answered before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes off course this is the good approach as http is asynchronous call so in that case better to call any fucntion/code within the success block of http.

But try to break your code as much as you can.
As in your use case you can call another function and call get request within there like this -

```
update(){
     this.http.post<any>("/ssservice", "products=" + body, options)
       .suscribe(
         complete: () => {
           this.anotherGetReuqest();
         });
    }

anotherGetReuqest() {
this.http.get<Product[]>("/ssservice")
   .subscribe({(data: Product[]) => products.push(...data),
    err => console.log(err)})
}
```

Comment: Same as th other answer. I think a better approach would be to return the observable and not the suscribed function. what do you think?

Comment: What do you mean by subscribed function? Where?  can you explain a bit more?

Comment: instead of returning `http.get().suscribe()` I would return `http.get()`then call suscribe in the `update()` function this way I could call another third function in a proper way.

Comment: Ohh you want to use/return a response of get request in `update()` method, then yes you can. I presume that you just want to call another function independently .

Comment: yes that was my question but I wanted your advice. returning `Observable` in `update()` function seems a best practice what do you think? Btw even for post request. this could b splitted into 2 different function returning `observable` at least that's what I've done

Comment: Yeah, it can be the best approach actually, But for post request I don't think this is needed

Answer (score 1):

I think @PardeepJain is telling

```
update(){
  this.http.post<any>("/ssservice", "products=" + body, options)
    .suscribe({
      complete: () => {
        this.getProduct()
      },
    });
}

getProduct () {
  this.http.get<Product[]>("/ssservice")
    .subscribe({
      (data: Product[]) => products.push(...data),
       err => console.log(err)})
}
```

Comment: One problem in your code is that I cannot call another function after `getProduct()` one solution would be to return `Observable` and not suscribed function